# Select Checkbox using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

According my requirement , in a form 5 check-box are implemented , like

```
<form action="#" method="post">    
    <input type="checkbox" class="ch-1" />   /* Need to select */    
    <input type="checkbox" class="ch-2" />   /* Need to select */    
    <input type="checkbox" class="bx-3" />    
    <input type="checkbox" class="bx-4" />    
    <input type="checkbox" class="ch-5" />    /* Need to select */   
    <input type="submit" value="Select" />        
</form>
```

Now I need to check those checkboxes which is having starting class name is ch- on submit click using jquery .

Comment: Why are you making these checkboxes checked on submitting form?

Instead you directly make these checkboxes checked in your HTML markup.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **[attribute-starts-with-selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** to target elements starting with class . and for selecting them, set property checked to true:

```
$('[class^="ch-"]').prop('checked',true);
```

Comment: @SatishUpadhyay: glad it helps. do upvote and accept the helped answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
 $("input[class^=ch-]").prop("checked",true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attribute selector` to get checkboxes which have class like ch-

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    var chkboxes = $('[class^=ch-]');
});
```

If you want to get only checked checkboxes then you can use :checked selector.

```
var chkboxes = $('[class^=ch-]:checked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery **[starts with ^](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)** selector,

```
$('#submit').click(function){
    $(':checkbox[class^="ch-"]').prop('checked',true);   

})
```

Just to get the checkboxes use `:checked`

```
$(':checkbox[class^="ch-"]:checked')
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : on submit event of form, select all `checkbox` with class name starting from 'ch-' by using [Start with selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) of jQuery.

```
$('form').submit(function(){
    $('[class^="ch-"]').prop('checked',true);
});
```